# visual studio 2012 project creation failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ide, visual-studio-2013

I have successfully installed `Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop`.

Whenever I try to create new C++ project it says: `... projet creation failed.`

Whenever I try to create Visual Basic project message box says: `Visual Studio does not have permissions to read the template information from the system registry. This is often caused by registry permissions problems.`.

I already tried to `Repair`, force uninstall with `wdexpress_full.exe /uninstall /force` and install `KB2781514` with no good. What should I do?

Just before installing `VS2012` I have uninstalled `VS2013`. Could this problem be cause by previously installed `VS2013`?

**update1**

I am running Windows 7.

**update2**

I have removed `VS2012` and installed `VC2010`. Same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging the Internet almost for 2 days I have finally found the solution [here](http://masteranza.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/solution-vs-c-2008-project-creation-failed-bug/) (seems like it took only a half of an hour for that guy)).

1. Open `regedit.exe`
2. Locate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.11.0`
3. Right click -> Permissions -> Advanced -> Owner
4. Select "Administrators" and click "OK"
5. Do the same to all subfolders which is under `VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.11.0`, if any (you might need to restart regedit to see them)
6. Right Click `VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.11.0` and click "Delete"
7. Set permissions for `VsWizard.WizCombo.11.0` folder and subfolders, and delete that one too
8. Now you shouldn’t have any folder called `VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.11.0` or `VsWizard.WizCombo.11.0`
9. Open `cmd.exe` with administrative rights
10. Navigate to your Microsoft Visual Studio IDE folder, by using the `cd` command. (usually `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` or `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE`)
11. Type `regsvr32.exe vswizard.dll` (you should get a window telling that you’ve registered that dll file)
12. Start `regedit.exe` again (if you haven’t), and locate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.11.0`. This should have been added again
13. Right Click -> Permissions, you should see "Administrators" and "SYSTEM" or something, click them both and enable `Full Control` and `Read`.
14. Do the same for subfolders (should’ve been done automatically), and do it for `VsWizard.WizCombo.11.0` and subfolders, which should’ve been added again.
15. Close `regedit.exe`
16. Start Visual Studio, create a new project, and watch how it works!

I guess this sould work for `vs2013` too, but it's my guess.

**update**

Also you can reset permissions for whole registry using [`reset registry permissions`](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/reset_registry_permissions.html) tool if other errors appear (e.g. unalbe to add lib files to project, broken icons etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The above didnt work for me as I kept being denied in regedit even though i was admin.

I found this on another site:

`psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe`

psexec is available from Microsoft here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

This gave me full registry access.  I tried to give admin owner to specific keys like above but VS 2012 express was still throwing that registry permission error.  So I finally just added Administrator to the permission list of the entire `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\` directory in regedit. Then gave admins full control.

This worked. I can now create a project without that infernal error!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions, but the below mentioned steps helped me at last. Please try out that if none of the above solutions worked for you.

- Go to Libraries\Documents folder
- Right click on the folder IISExpress and click Properties
- Go to Advanced options
- Under Compress or Encrypt attributes, please uncheck the checkbox
  'Encrypt contents to secure data'
- Click Ok and apply.

Now try to create a project, hope you won't get the error again.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me.

I've managed to fix it by using the following running in command prompt (as administrator) on Windows 7:

```
FOR /R C:\ %G IN (*.dll) DO "%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" /s "%G"
```

([Source](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/37307-63-interface-supported))

Answer (score 0):

There can be some troubles with JS registration. So, as mentioned before, try use

`regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\jscript.dll`

And do not forget the `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\jscript.dll` on x64 systems